# Merge [package] and [packages]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) and [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages)

There doesn't really seem to be a need for these two to be separate tags, for the same reason that it would be silly to have [database] and [databases] be separate tags.

Comment: I did not downvote/upvote this, but I believe a clean-up should be done, but not necessarily adding a synonym

Answer (score 7):

Both tags are a hot mess

[package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package)

> Package broadly refers to two things: 1) a usable unit/component of built/compiled of software, or 2) a partition of the global namespace (java).

Multiple definitions for a tag never bode well

[packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages)

> For questions relating to the use of or naming of packages in Java, Scala, Python and other languages.

Sounds off-topic (how to name things is not part of SO)

I would suggest we do the following

1. Retag the Java questions to [java-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-package)
2. Make a new overall tag (say [software-package] to remove any Java doubts), write a more concise excerpt, and synonym [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages) and [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) to this new tag

Comment: Packages are what the packagers says it is. tar files are packages, zip files are packages, deb files are packages. Anything that has the word packages without the packager is not useful, and the interesting thing is the actual packager, not the package itself.

Comment: @Braiam in your reasoning *package* is at best about the bytes (format, location, order), right? If I'm writing  an unzip tool and don't know what the byte 42 means I would tag with *package*?

Comment: What about packages in other languages rather than Java? (I believe they exist)

Comment: @rene if you are writing a unzip tool and you don't use the readily available libraries that can figure it out for you, you have bigger problems.

Comment: I suggest burninating [tag:package] (for the software package usage). It’s as useless as [tag:api].

Comment: Since this question is closed as a duplicate, but this disambiguation remains, I've referenced this answer in a new question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424907/1108305