# Misdelivery of [package] and [java-package] (disambiguation/deduplication needed)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are two tags that deal with Java packages: [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) and [java-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-package).

The [java-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-package) tag is clearly and specifically for questions relating to Java packages.  The [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) tag, on the other hand, is a tag that refers to multiple things, including Java packages.  Per the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/package/info):

> Package broadly refers to two things: 1) a usable unit/component of built/compiled software, or 2) a partition of the global namespace (Java).
>
> ---
>
> Package may refer to a software component or the action of creating a package. The component could be a portion of a whole system, or the whole system itself, or any level of granularity between. Typical packaging mechanisms include: tar, jar, zip, rpm, war, exe. In this context it may also be used as a verb: "I was packaging my software and...".
>
> Package is also a term from the java world to refer to the mechanism used to partition the global namespace with the intention of making it possible of having two classes with the same name and of creating a logical structure in which classes may be held. In java packages are most commonly represented by directories. Package is also a java keyword used at the start of a class file to indicate the package to which the class belongs. This is important because of 'package' scoped access rules, which allow classes in the same package to access a field/method/class.
>
> Because of the ambiguity here it is best to use other tags to help define the meaning of this one. If you're asking about java packages, please include the Java tag. If you're asking about packaging up your software for deployment/use add other appropriate tags, such as 'Maven', 'Make', 'Ant', etc.

[java-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-package) is a relatively tiny tag with only 91 questions.  [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) currently has 16,664 questions, 2,235 of which also have the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365322/1108305) to a related closed question suggested the following:

> I would suggest we do the following
>
> 1. Retag the Java questions to [java-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-package)
> 2. Make a new overall tag (say [software-package] to remove any Java doubts), write a more concise excerpt, and synonym [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages) and [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) to this new tag

I think retagging the Java questions and removing it from the definition of [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) is a good idea.  The other usages of packages might want to be burninated, or maybe split apart into various specific tags.

What does the community think we should do here?

Comment: The retagging for java questions sounds reasonable, for any other question though... not sure if we would need `[package]` at all. It could very well be conflated to just mean the same as *library*, which in itself is useless as a tag.

Comment: Is there a way of bulk changing something like [tag:package] + [tag:java] to [tag:java-package] + [tag:java]?  Or would that need to be manually done for each of the 2,235 matching questions?  What's the typical approach?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're half right. Converting [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)+[package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) to [java-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-package) is a good plan (unless there is something more specific you can use) and more power to your elbow with that cleanup, but it sounds like [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) itself is a confused mess that doesn't help anyone and will eventually need burnination. Changing [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) to [software-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-package) won't help!

Comment: In fairness, I myself never actually argued for keeping `package` around as `software-package`. :-) "The other usages of packages might want to be burninated, or maybe split apart into various specific tags."

So I think your stance and mine are basically the same.